# targets in columnDefs of Datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable

The [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) tells us the way we can use 'targets'
in columnDefs. But is there any way we can use it dynamically? For example, I have a global array (containing column numbers) which I update every time certain function is carried out on datatable. I want to render those columns in the global array in a particular fashion. I need to know  if there is any way in which I could do this.

```
"columnDefs":[
  {
    "targets": hide_them,//name of the global array
    "render": //some function
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [**documentation**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) `Target` of `columnDefs` in Datatable must use for below approach

0 or a positive integer column index counting from the left

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 0,
      "searchable": false
    } ]
} );
```

A negative integer such as column index counting from the right

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
      "columnDefs": [ {
          "targets": -0,
          "searchable": false
        } ]
    } );
```

_all - A string - class name will be matched for all column as default work

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
          "columnDefs": [ {
              "targets": '_all',
              "searchable": false
            } ]
        } );
```

Comment: Yes, all these uses of 'targets' are clearly evident from the documentation. Neither those nor the above ways (which are very much similar to those in the documentation) do not cater to the difficulty in question.